# File Transfers in Nodejs (ftp)

Tags: node.js, ftp, file-transfer

I'm new to nodejs, and I am trying to exchange files between two systems.

These systems know Ip address of each other, and are able to exchange messages using tcp sockets. But now I want them to transfer files to each other. I think it would be implemented using ftp. Or if there's a better way, please tell.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you please try to copy your files with SCP OR rsync command.